# Regular expression instead of using split function in the format num * num * num

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Instead of using the split function I want to use a eegular expression in the format num * num * num.

I want to validate an input so that the user can input only in the format 2 * 3 * 4, ie anynumber * anynumber * anynumber. I was successful in doing so by using the split function. Is there a way to do this using a regular expression in Javascript?

Comment: i could do it like this `code` function fun()
{
  var dpattern = /\*/i;
  
  var str = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var order = dpattern.exec(str);
  if(order)
  {
   var n=str.split("*");
   
   var a = n[0];
   var b = n[1];
   var c = n[2];
   var d = a*b*c;
   alert(d); 
    
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

In pieces, you want it to have at least one number, and then any number of (any number of spaces, an asterisk, any number of spaces, and then another number). Try this:

```
^\d+(\s*\*\s*\d)*$
```

The `\d+` is any number of digits (excluding negatives and decimals and starting with any number of zeroes), `\s*` is zero or more whitespace characters, and `\*` is an asterisk (preceded by a backspace so it isn't confused to mean "zero or more"). The parentheses group the end together so you can have any number of those at the end. You will need to add a `^` and `$` to ensure that no other random characters are ignored at the start and end.

You can use forward slashes to denote a regular expression in Javascript, so:

```
var pattern = /^\d+(\s*\*\s*\d)*$/;
pattern.test("2 * 3 * 4");   // true
pattern.test("002  * 3* 04");   // true
pattern.test("2 # 3 # 4");   // false
pattern.test("2.0 * 3 * 4");   // false
pattern.test("-2 * 3 * 4");   // false
```

If you want decimals, negative numbers, leading or trailing spaces, or any other sort of feature, you'll need to tweak the pattern a bit...but hopefully this gives you enough to go on!

Comment: This comes out valid for other special characters also 2 # 2 # 2

Comment: @Ivin It also passes for "2 # lemon ! BMW". You may need to add `^` and `$` for the `test` method to work in Javascript. Otherwise it will find the first number, decide that you have no instances of the bit in parentheses, and still return true.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
document.write("2 * 3 * 4".match(/[0-9]+[\s]?\*[\s]?[0-9]+[\s]?\*[\s]?[0-9]+/));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the pattern using the following:

This pattern matches single-digit numbers (digit, star, digit, star, digit)

```
^\d\*\d\*\d$
```

This pattern matches numbers of any length (number, star, number, star, number)

```
^\d+\*\d+\*\d+$
```

You can also allow whitespace using the \s identifier. The following allows a single space between the numbers and symbols:

```
^\d\s?\*\s?\d\s?\*\s?\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be what you want :

```
^\d+\s*\*\s*\d+\s*\*\s*\d+$
```

It allows **integer*integer*integer** with zero or more spaces between number and `*`.

For allowing decimal part, use :

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\*\s*\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\*\s*\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

For negative numbers add `-?` to allow an optional `-` like:

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\*\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\*\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

`^\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\*\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\*\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*$` allows zero or more spaces before and after the expression. For capturing the numbers, use capture groups :

For `^\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*\*\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*\*\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*$`

`$1`, `$3` and `$5` give the 3 numbers respectively.

If capturing is not required and you want allow two or more factors,

```
-?\d+(\.\d+)?(\s*\*\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)+
```

would be better.

Comment: Since this is validating the input, I think he doesn't care whether the result can be captured or not - the solution can be generalized for arbitrary number of factors.

Comment: `-?\d+(\.\d+)?(\s*\*\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)+` would do that